# SFTP full file path for a set of files

Tags: python, sftp

Let's say I have a list of files, such as

```
files = ["C:\\MyDir\\some_file.txt",
         "C:\\MyDir\\another_file.txt",
         "C:\\MyDir\\some_file.old"]
```

And I want to pull out the ".txt" files that start with "some". I use the standard fnmatch.filter method:

```
my_files = fnmatch.filter([os.path.basename(i) for i in files], "some*.txt")
```

Which returns ["some_file.txt"]. Now let's say those files were actually on an SFTP site, and I want to download them from the SFTP site after filtering. How do I get the full file path(s) for the files I want to download?

```
os.path.abspath("some_file.txt")
```

will not work for obvious reasons. I could simply prefix my filter pattern with another wildcard ("*"), but that's a workaround. Is there a clean way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the full path name, then you'll have to apply the filter on the full pathname. The `fnmatch` patterns are a little limited, and the are converted to regex anyway, so why not just use `re` directly:

```
import re
files = ["C:\\MyDir\\some_file.txt",
     "C:\\MyDir\\another_file.txt",
     "C:\\MyDir\\some_file.old"]

patern = re.compile(r"\\some[^\\]*\.txt$", re.I)
filtered_files = [f for f in files if pattern.search(f)]
```